# 500 server error when submitting form but no logs were found

Tags: ajax, apache2, digital-ocean

I have a site that has a signup form , can be accessed [here](http://siral.marketing/auth/signup)

Everytime i try to submit the POST it returns back as a 500 error, however when i tried to check the server error logs.. i find it empty

[image]

for some reason i kind of suspect it has to do with my apache2 setup as this is a codecanyon base code, so i doubt there is an error in the code.. here's what i have in my virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                      
                                                        
    ServerName siral.marketing                          
    #ServerAlias www.siral.marketing                    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                     
    DocumentRoot /var/www/smmpanel                      
                                                        
    <Directory "/var/www/smmpanel">                     
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews       
        Order allow,deny                                
        AllowOverride All                               
        Allow from all                                  
    </Directory>                                        
                                                        
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/smmpanel_error.log       
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined     
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In response it states issue that it cannot locate `payments_model` see [here](https://imgur.com/a/dkeRRG2).

Comment: As @Chandan stated, you have an error 500 on your server. If you are confident that you included your model `Payments_model` then check your `include` directives and compare it to filenames - I mean, the server might be case sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not an issue with the apache. If you using Codeigniter please check the file name and class names (check all models and the controllers). Because those are case-sensitive on production servers. On the local machine, it may not show this error.

When you're using FTP for this scenario, try to delete the destination file first on the remote machine and then copy the new file to the server. Because sometimes replacing or rename may not work properly for change the letter case of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the URL you have given, looks like its only a modal file is missing. `Unable to locate the model you have specified: Payments_model`.

Check the screenshot for better idea.

Try the firefox network tab while submitting your form.

Also check the file and complete directory name or you can paste the code in your question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that access rights for cache or log file folders are not set correctly.